# What exactly is Cramer-Wold device? (What's the difference b/w Cramer-Wold theorem and Cramer-Wold device?)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I'm a bit confused about the exact statement of the Cramer-Wold device. I've read multiple sources which seem to be giving different definitions (the first one is more common).

1. Random vectors $X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfy $X_n \rightarrow_d X$ if and only if $\langle a, X_n \rangle \rightarrow_d \langle a, X \rangle$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

([Source](https://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/580s/581/LECTNOTES/ch2.pdf): Proposition 2.7)

2. If $\langle a, X_n \rangle \rightarrow_d \langle a, X \rangle$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|a\| = 1$, then $X_n \rightarrow_d X$.

([Source](http://web.mit.edu/14.381/www/ho6.pdf): Theorem 13)

Also, What's the difference between Cramer-Wold theorem and Cramer-Wold device? Is there a difference?

Comment: Both statements are equivalent, so any of these may be used for referring to Cramer-Wold device. Also, my personal impression is that they are just two different names for the same result.

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you please clarify (maybe as an answer) how the two statements are equivalent? One is talking about all a in R^d while the second one refers only to a in R^d with ||a|| = 1.

Comment: It is a consequence of the following fact: if $(Y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of RVs converging in distribution to $Y$, then $$cY_n \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} cY$$ for any constant $c$. Now, in order to check that Version 1 implies Version 2, assume Version 1 as well as the assumption of Version 2. Then write any $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ as $\mathbf{a}=r\mathbf{u}$ for some $r\geq 0$ and $\|\mathbf{u}\|=1$ and then show that $\langle\mathbf{a},X_n\rangle=r\langle\mathbf{u},X_n\rangle$ converges in distribution to $r\langle\mathbf{u},X_n\rangle=\langle\mathbf{a},X_n\rangle$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! :)